# Unity 2D, unstable jump

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I've been busy on a platformer game and currently have an unstable jump. It sometimes jumps higher then normal.

My jump:

```
if (onGround == true) {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey("up") || jump == true) {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpHeight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

If any of you know a solution/tip it would help me out a lot!

Comment: I usually just directly alter the rigidbody velocity for jumping and use addforce for horizontal movement... Try that

Comment: is the above code in `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`? If it's in `Update()`, you might be running through that code more than once before `FixedUpdate()` has a chance to set the onGround to false.

Comment: It's in an Update(), but I fixed it earlier today by setting onGround to false within the jump. I noticed that it sometimes was onGround a little bit longer then it should have been and it caused the AddForce to give an extra push.